# Form application - How do I create a form that generates a random time in C#

Tags: c#

How do I create a form that generates random time?

It will generate a random time when the button is pressed and will produce a random time again when I press it again.

Comment: Please tag your questions properly. C# and C are two different programming languages - That way you will increase the chance of having an answer to your question!

Comment: Furthermore, always try first, look for existing similar questions, and then ask a new one keeping in mind to share the code you've tried - Broad and unclear questions, like the one above, generally get deleted!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this in a blank console application, after referencing `System.Windows.Forms.dll`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var label = new Label();
    var button = new Button { Text = "next date" };
    var layout = new FlowLayoutPanel { Controls = { label, button } };
    var form = new Form { Controls = { layout } };
    button.Click += (s, e) => label.Text = new DateTime(random.Next()).ToString();
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have `Label` called `label1` and `Button` called `button1`, which has `Click` event hadnler called `button1_Click`. Then define body of `button1_Click` method like this:

```
// better idea is to have this as class property,
// than creating it everytime you want to use it
Random r = new Random();
// Here you could use one of methods: AddSeconds, AddMinutes, etc.,
// Choose one that fits best. Also you could choose othe base date
// than DateTime.MinValue
DateTime d = DateTime.MinValue.AddSeconds(r.Next());

label1.Text = d.ToString();
```